# Web socket use 80/443 port to send message but they randomly choose port>1000 to receive incoming messages

Tags: javascript, tcp, websocket, port, firewall

Web socket use 80/443 port to send message but they randomly choose port>1000 to receive incoming messages.Is there any way so that we can fixed the incoming port also. Please help anyone who has worked with web socket or can guide me where i can find useful stuff related to  this problem.

Comment: That's the normal behavior of TCP connections: pick some (more or less random) port at the client and connect to a specific port on the server. Nothing to worry about and if you simply write to the socket at the server side the data will find their way to the client.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the answer  but what i was trying is to write a script which runs on a vm ( that means only specific ports can be opened) i.e. on the client and i am using some slack api's so don't have control on server side.So if there is any way in which we can get control over the desired ports then that will work in my case.

Comment: First you cannot control from within the browser the local port used for a TCP connection (which includes Websocket connections). Apart from that I don't really understand your use case. If it is a firewall in context of a VM then one usually allows connections from the VM to a specific port, i.e. does not restrict on the client port but only on the server port.